# How to disable Safari Frequently Visited?

Tags: safari

[image]How can you disable the Frequently Visited section in the Safari 9 Favorites tab?

I do not like how these auto-generate and need to be manually removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see now that it can be disabled under the "Bookmarks" menu. Simple as that.